# Prepend timestamp to stderr before logging

Tags: bash

I am trying to figure out how to prepend the timestamp to stderr before it gets logged to a file.

I have the following

```
sudo apt-get -y update 2>> error.log

sudo apt-get -y upgrade 2>> error.log
```

But have not had any luck getting the timestamp prepended

Comment: does your `apt-get update` displays a timestamp?

Comment: Not my default no, but I just figured it out.

Comment: See: [Prepending a timestamp to each line of output from a command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/26728/74329)

Comment: Not what I am wanting. That requires downloading a package to do it.

Comment: There are 9 answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
(
    sudo apt-get -y update
    sudo apt-get -y upgrade
) 2> >(while IFS= read -r line; do echo "$(date): $line"; done > error.log)
```

Group all the commands in a subshell and use [process substitution](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html) to redirect their combined output to a loop. The loop can read a line at a time and echo them back with timestamps prepended.

This technique is nice because the individual `apt-get` commands don't need to be modified, and `> error.log` is only needed once at the end.

See also:

- [Understanding "IFS= read -r line"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/209123/understanding-ifs-read-r-line)

Comment: It's logging all out the output, not just stderr

Comment: `exec 2> >(while ...)` at the beginning of the script would be even more user-friendly I think.

Comment: Are you sure? I tested it and it worked as intended: stdout went to the terminal while stderr was saved in `error.log`.

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo apt-get -y update 2>> ( while read line; do echo "$(date): ${line}"; done >> error.log)
sudo apt-get -y upgrade 2>> ( while read line; do echo "$(date): ${line}"; done >> error.log)
```

Comment: This is not a valid bash syntax.

Comment: Funny. Because it works without errors.

Comment: `done` is missing and you use `>> (...)` instead of `> >(...)`.

Comment: I did forget the done at the end, but the redirection you sent isn't correct, the way i have it works. The way you sent errors out.

Comment: You must be typing it wrong. I checked and can confirm what @Cyrus said: `2> >(` works, while `2>> (` produces `syntax error near unexpected token '('`.

Comment: I get the error you got when I have it the way @Cyrus stated.